# How can I install Windows 7 on a disk with dynamic partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

My PC has a single drive, with currently two partitions, Win7 x86 and Data, plus two other (OEM and system-reserved)

[image: disk manager screenshot]

I want to create a third partition to install Win7 x64, but the installer didn't like the fact that partitions were dynamic. I don't know if there's a way to recreate basic partitions, and make my data partition dynamic, since I read that I can have 4 basic partitions? I have GParted liveCD, but before I'd prefer to ask here what is the best partitionning option.

Comment: Terminology nit: You don't have "dynamic partitions". You have a "dynamic disk". This means that the standard ("Basic") partitioning scheme doesn't exist on it. Except for the 78 MB boot partition you are seeing not partitions, but volumes. A volume in dynamic disks can be made up of many discontiguous ranges of blocks and even of ranges of blocks that exist on multiple physical disks. Yes, you can have more than four volumes on a dynamic disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can convert your dynamic disk to Basic using this software [Dynamic Disk Converter](http://www.dynamic-disk.com/download.html)
- Other Methods are listed [here](http://www.dynamic-disk.com/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html)

Make sure Read this  [First](http://strangelyperfect.tv/6415/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used Magic Partition Manager from MiniTools, it did the conversion for the same price and does partition management.

Answer (score 0):

GParted didn't help, but I was able to convert partitions from dynamic to basic with [Magic Partition Manager](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-magic-free.html) from MiniTools (29 USD). Then I recreated partition and I could install Windows on it.